# How to destroy the ViewModel object as soon as View is removed from the screen

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, viewmodel

I have some code inside `InitializeDataViewer()` which is required to be executed each time one view is loaded. I have kept the code in the `ViewModel` constructor. My problem occurs when I come back to get that view back - the constructor is not executed. Is there any way to destroy the ViewModel object or some other way to execute the constructor code?

```
public Data_Viewer_View_Model()
{
    InitializeDataViewer();//this has to be executed eachtime the view is loaded.
    dataViewerModel = new Data_Viewer_Model();

    objBackToDatabase = new ButtonCommand<string>(dataViewerModel.BackToDatabase, dataViewerModel.IsValid);
    objBackToDatabase.ReturnValueChanged += objBackToDatabase_ReturnValueChanged;
}
```

`InitializeDataViewer()` initializes some variables that are binded, but since it is not getting initialized older values are shown.

Comment: Instead of having that code in the constructor why not have it in the Window Load/Activate event?

Comment: is it possible while trying the mvvm pattern? Thank you @peeyush for your time.

Comment: I dont think MVVM pattern has any relevance here, currently your method call is in viewModel, and if you move it to window load event, then also it will be in viewModel, so it is not relevant here. Now what you are doing inside the InitializeDataViewer and should it be in the viewModel might be more relevent question, but since I do not know what is inside, I cannot answer that.

Comment: You've not explained why the viewmodel is persisted and or how the viewmodel and it's instantiation relates to the view. Sounds like something is keeping a reference to your view and that keeps a reference to the viewmodel.  You could maybe move the initialisation code to a public method in the viewmodel, call that from the ctor and whenever you do what you're doing.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correct, the way to solve it would be to move the initialization of the properties to a method on your VM ( ViewModel). Let's name it Reset()

Then bind to the VM properties from your view.

If you want to reset the values again when you show the view. I would simply let whatever code that is in charge of navigation to call Reset() on the VM. Normally when I do Navigation I always have a NavigatedTo() method and a NavigatedFrom() method in my ViewModels that I let the Navigation service call. So in NavigatedTo you could call Reset(). And in the VM constructor you would also call Reset()